# Instructing ReSharper that a field is-not-null when other property is 'true'

Tags: c#, resharper

I have a class where I use a property like `Exists` that returns `true` when the field `_value` is not `null`.

This field is later used to create a `StreamReader` from it. When I use it `ReSharper` is warning me that it might be `null` but since I prevent it with `if(Exists)` earlier it won't be.

I disabled the warning it with a comment but I was wondering whether there is a cleaner way or some annotation or other trick to make `ReSharper` understand that it's safe to use `_value` when `Exists == true`?

```
internal class User
{
    private readonly string _value;

    internal User([NotNull] string name, [CanBeNull] string value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public bool Exists => !(_value is null);

    public async Task CopyToAsync(Stream stream)
    {
        if (Exists)
        {
            // ReSharper disable once AssignNullToNotNullAttribute - '_value' won't be null here
            using (var valueStream = _value.ToStreamReader()) 
            {
                await valueStream.BaseStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at Contract Annotations? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Contract_Annotations.html. Not sure if they can inspect other state of a class or just parameters

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 yeah, I'm using them in several places already. The thing is that they work only with methods and their parameters. I couldn't figure out any trick that would help in this particular situation.

Comment: bah that stinks. I actually just looked at the whole list of available Annotations and there's nothing that would cover this. My bet is that its because in the general sense you'd have no guarantees if the app were multithreaded. (ignoring the readonly for the moment). That said I know the JetBrains team takes suggestions on new Annotations and it's also possible to write your own

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 _it's also possible to write your own_ - really? :-o I didn't know that. I'll check this out. This sounds like THE solution.

Comment: I'm *pretty sure* that you can, but... Its possible I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

This is a frustrating problem that I'm experiencing myself. I'm not sure if you ever found a Resharper annotation that worked, but I wanted to add information about eliminating the equivalent warning from Visual Studio's analyzer. I would've expected Resharper to also respect it, but my experience is that it does not, unfortunately.

Here's how it's used internally for String.IsNullOrEmpty().

```
bool IsNullOrEmpty([NotNullWhen(false)] string? value)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis